# How can I protect Edit and delete access for particular tables in sqlite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I am developing a sqlite editor for learning purpose, here everyone can create delete or edit in new tables, but not in default table. Because I am created some default table for their learning purpose. So I want to protect the default table and its values. Is it possible?
I found the following link but im not understood anything http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to says:

> However, if the same
>   database file is opened by a version of SQLite that omits
>   the -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION compile-time option, then the sqlite_user
>   table will be readable by anybody and writeable by anybody

And in any case, SQLite databases are just files, and could be read or modified directly.

The only way to more reliably protect data in SQLite is to put the data into a separate database file, and protect that file with whatever mechanism your OS offers.